# Why is shutdown.exe not running in PowerShell on Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11, shutdown

Problem with shutdown.exe command in Windows 11.

Using PowerShell (Run as administrator) And having run Set-ExcecutionPolicy

Notepad, MMC, Resmon All execute perfectly, but not shutdown, here is the resulting verbiage.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> shutdown
Usage: C:\Windows\system32\shutdown.exe [/i | /l | /s | /sg | /r | /g | /a | /p | /h | /e | /o] [/hybrid] [/soft] [/fw] [/f]
    [/m \\computer][/t xxx][/d [p|u:]xx:yy [/c "comment"]]

    No args    Display help. This is the same as typing /?.
    /?         Display help. This is the same as not typing any options.
    /i         Display the graphical user interface (GUI).
               This must be the first option.
    /l         Log off. This cannot be used with /m or /d options.
    /s         Shutdown the computer.
    /sg        Shutdown the computer. On the next boot, if Automatic Restart Sign-On
               is enabled, automatically sign in and lock last interactive user.
               After sign in, restart any registered applications.
    /r         Full shutdown and restart the computer.
    /g         Full shutdown and restart the computer. After the system is rebooted,
               if Automatic Restart Sign-On is enabled, automatically sign in and
               lock last interactive user.
               After sign in, restart any registered applications.
    /a         Abort a system shutdown.
               This can only be used during the time-out period.
               Combine with /fw to clear any pending boots to firmware.
    /p         Turn off the local computer with no time-out or warning.
               Can be used with /d and /f options.
    /h         Hibernate the local computer.
               Can be used with the /f option.
    /hybrid    Performs a shutdown of the computer and prepares it for fast startup.
               Must be used with /s option.
    /fw        Combine with a shutdown option to cause the next boot to go to the
               firmware user interface.
    /e         Document the reason for an unexpected shutdown of a computer.
    /o         Go to the advanced boot options menu and restart the computer.
               Must be used with /r option.
    /m \\computer Specify the target computer.
    /t xxx     Set the time-out period before shutdown to xxx seconds.
               The valid range is 0-315360000 (10 years), with a default of 30.
               If the timeout period is greater than 0, the /f parameter is
               implied.
    /c "comment" Comment on the reason for the restart or shutdown.
               Maximum of 512 characters allowed.
    /f         Force running applications to close without forewarning users.
               The /f parameter is implied when a value greater than 0 is
               specified for the /t parameter.
    /d [p|u:]xx:yy  Provide the reason for the restart or shutdown.
               p indicates that the restart or shutdown is planned.
               u indicates that the reason is user defined.
               If neither p nor u is specified the restart or shutdown is
               unplanned.
               xx is the major reason number (positive integer less than 256).
               yy is the minor reason number (positive integer less than 65536).

Reasons on this computer:
(E = Expected U = Unexpected P = planned, C = customer defined)

Type    Major   Minor   Title

 U      0   0   Other (Unplanned)
 U      0   5   Other Failure: System Unresponsive
 U      5   15  System Failure: Stop error
 U      5   19  Security issue (Unplanned)
 U      6   11  Power Failure: Cord Unplugged
 U      6   12  Power Failure: Environment
  P     7   0   Legacy API shutdown
```

**EDIT:**

Solved myself! With a little help of your comments, and support.

Shutdown needs /s (On its own)

To be clear, Shutdown /s I was trying Shutdown /s /t:120 - Silly me. It should be /t 120 (no colon) I started troubleshooting by stripping down to plain "Shutdown"

Comment: Shutdown from Powershell works here (Windows 11 23H2) try running DISM / SFC   ...............    (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: What exactly is your PowerShell command?

Comment: shutdown without parameters may indeed display the help, depending on the windows version. some older versions of windows and server versions for example. try shutdown /s for example

Comment: @OP - I assumed you used a parameter (you showed them).  shutdown /s  will shut down.

Comment: Solved myself!  With a little help of your comments, and support.

Shutdown needs /s (On its own)  To be clear, Shutdown /s
I was trying Shutdown /s /t:120 - Silly me.  It should be /t 120 (no colon)
I started troubleshooting by stripping down to plain "Shutdown" - silly me again!

Answer (score 2):

Shutdown requires arguments.

The Help text does clearly state, in the first row of the argument explanations:

> No args    Display help. This is the same as typing /?.

So, you're seeing the expected and correct result of running Shutdown with no commands. The simplest command would be `shutdown /s` which is the command to shut the computer down.

If you wish to simply shut down the computer using this command, you must use arguments appropriate to your requirements.

Answer (score -3):

It appears xx:yy is mandatory.

Comment: No it's not, but I can see what you're saying. Syntax for CMD help is usually that items contained within the square brackets are options, and items not contained in square brackets are required. In this case you have to read the remainder of the instructions to see that running with no args IS allowed, so there are no required arguments, BUT, no args means it will display the help, as it did.